# Error importing Event from dash.dependencies

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working with Dash and its dependencies. Worked well before and now I get an Import Error. Any ideas for sorting this?

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Output, Event
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly
```

ImportError: cannot import name 'Event' from 'dash.dependencies' (/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dash/dependencies.py)

Answer (score 1):

Event was removed in the 0.37 version  of Dash, that's why you cannot import it. 
You can use Input instead, if your project allows it.